# Emu8086 assembler not reading correctly

Tags: wine, ram

I installed WineHQ yesterday to run `emu8086`. The installation of `emu8086` went smoothly. But when I was working on the software I realized that I can't modify the value in memory while emulating.
People say that these Windows programs work fine with Wine. Any help?In windows, I was able to modify these zeroes but not happening here.
[image: Picture]

Comment: Why?! I would always opt for Linux based programs https://sourceforge.net/projects/pcemu/  should do the job for this.

Comment: I downloaded PCEmu but i don't know how to install it. Can you give some directions? @Rinzwind

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm years late, but I came across this question a few days ago while searching for a fix to this particular problem. Leaving aside the fact that this software looks totally abandoned, it stills being used for teaching, in my case I even depend on this for some exams (yeah, my teachers should start looking for some modern solution).

Anyways, I managed to solve this by changing the font of the "memory list" (options>fonts and colors) to some windows-native monospaced typeface, like Andale Mono, only then the memory window will allow user input.

[image: Random Access Memory window]

I still have the problem with the program widget not being visible in the task manager while running. I'm using kubuntu, not sure if this particular issue will occur using another DE.